# javascript/jQuery anonymous functions to populate an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I was just wondering if building an array in javascript was possible using a function like so. I have a variable that is getting the margins of a series of elements using `$(ele).css('margin');`. This returns a string of `0px 0px 0px 0px` where I only want the left property to check whether it's been animated `-=` left.

I can do a similar function but I know there must be a better way. Here's my example:

```
var marginsLeft = new array();
$(ele).each(function(i){
    var r = $(i).css('margin').split(" ");
    marginsLeft[i]=r[3];
});
```

I'm not entirely sure how to simplify this, but I'm sure it's possible :) thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work, yes. However, just getting `css("margin-left")` might be easier…

Comment: `$(i)` won't work, since the first parameter or [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is the index in the element set. To get the element, either use `this` or the second parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var marginsLeft = $(ele).map(function() { 
    return parseInt($(this).css('margin-left'), 10);
}).get();
```

**Update:** as pointed out by @undefined, if you want a regular array you should also call [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) on the result. Otherwise, you'll have a jQuery wrapped array. It is array-like, so it can be used as an array in many contexts, but not in others (in particular, it may not have the native `Array` methods).

Also, to convert the result to a number you can use `parseInt` (which will ignore the letters and use only the digits), remembering to explicitate the base (10).

Comment: `map` returns a jQuery wrapped array, for getting the basic array, `get` method should be used.

Comment: @undefined I'm unfamiliar with `get`, what do you mean? Should I use `map` and then call `get` on the result (to unwrap the array)?

Comment: Yes, just call `get` after `map` method. http://api.jquery.com/map/, note that we have 2 map methods, you are not using `$.map`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: Just logged the `map` function. It returned this: `["0px"]`. Guessing that's what he means by wrapped? So the value is an array key rather than a value which would be preferred?

Comment: @Beneto nope, that is something else. See my updated answer. For more info about what a "wrapped jQuery object" is, see [this](http://www.vfstech.com/?p=40) for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [docs for `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/): The first parameter of the callback function is the index, the array element (DOM node) can be accessed either as the second parameter or the `this` value. So, use

```
var marginsLeft = []; // literal shortcut for "new Array()"
$(ele).each(function(i, el){
    marginsLeft[i] = $(el).css('margin-left');
});
```

You also might have a look at the [`.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/), but that returns a jQuery wrapper object instead of an array.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `css('margin-left')` instead

Comment: Now I feel stupid. lol but my question was, is there a way of creating an array using a function. `a = new array(function(r){return 'blah';});`. Sort of similar to the php function array_map?

Comment: please see the answer from mgibsonbr, I recommend it